# understanding fio test results - 90th percentiles benchmark - Latency --> avg/stdev?

Tags: performance, storage, random, benchmark, fio

What are the relationships in storage benchmarking with fio between the average(avg) and standard deviation (stdev) at latency?

Avg / stdev at latency is important for sequential or random test?

Most I/O subsystems are very well tuned that the standard deviation has little significance for sequential accesses. Furthermore, it is of interest how the standard deviation is with the random test.  is that right?

I was advised that in cases where the avg/stdev ratio related to latency is
5 %, the system is still problem-free
in cases where the system is optimal 10%
but at higher rates there is a problem in the system.

fio --rw=randrw --name=test_zufaellig_oci  --bs=4k --direct=1 --size=10G --ioengine=libaio --runtime=5400 --time_based

OCI

test_zufaellig_oci: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=16244: Thu Dec 29 17:16:45 2022
read: IOPS=1313, BW=5255KiB/s (5381kB/s)(27.1GiB/5400001msec)
slat (usec): min=7, max=1665, avg=16.39, stdev= 6.30
clat (usec): min=3, max=202186, avg=354.88, stdev=167.22
lat (usec): min=290, max=202206, **avg=371.52, stdev=167.53**
clat percentiles (usec):
|  1.00th=[  310],  5.00th=[  318], 10.00th=[  322], 20.00th=[  330],
| 30.00th=[  334], 40.00th=[  338], 50.00th=[  343], 60.00th=[  351],
| 70.00th=[  355], 80.00th=[  363], 90.00th=[  383], 95.00th=[  408],
| 99.00th=[  498], 99.50th=[  611], 99.90th=[ 1762], 99.95th=[ 2376],
| 99.99th=[ 6128]
bw (  KiB/s): min=  816, max= 6096, per=100.00%, avg=5263.74, stdev=325.49, samples=10781
iops        : min=  204, max= 1524, avg=1315.94, stdev=81.37, samples=10781

---

AWS

test_zufaellig_aws: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=2960: Thu Dec 29 17:16:54 2022
read: IOPS=315, BW=1261KiB/s (1291kB/s)(6648MiB/5400007msec)
slat (usec): min=6, max=107, avg=19.35, stdev= 4.90
clat (usec): min=190, max=113470, avg=1472.25, stdev=2373.50
lat (usec): min=207, max=113491, **avg=1492.51, stdev=2374.87**
clat percentiles (usec):
|  1.00th=[  318],  5.00th=[  347], 10.00th=[  363], 20.00th=[  392],
| 30.00th=[  412], 40.00th=[  429], 50.00th=[  453], 60.00th=[  482],
| 70.00th=[  529], 80.00th=[  644], 90.00th=[ 6915], 95.00th=[ 7046],
| 99.00th=[ 7177], 99.50th=[ 7242], 99.90th=[ 7504], 99.95th=[ 7635],
| 99.99th=[14091]
bw (  KiB/s): min=  144, max= 4184, per=100.00%, avg=1262.50, stdev=1493.09, samples=10783
iops        : min=   36, max= 1046, avg=315.63, stdev=373.27, samples=10783

Comment: I fail to understand your question. The relationship between average and standard deviation is strictly mathematical and therefore does not depend on the benchmark. If that is your question then it would probably better fit on other sites than U&L_SE. Are you looking for some rationale linking avg and stdev to latency in precise I/O operations under Linux ?

Comment: The professor said that there is such logic. If avg/stdev is 5%, the system is optimal.

My question is whether this relationship is valid for sequentiell or only for random tests?

I'm open to advice in general.

I measure and compare the I/O Performance of the system both in OCI and AWS with FIO .

I make comparisons by looking at the number of IOPS in random tests and Bandwidth (bw) values in sequential tests.

If I see a big difference von Performance, then I look at the latency 90th percentile.

Comment: **avg / stdev ???** are you sure it is not just the inverse ( stdev / avg ) ?

Comment: yes avg/stdev is important. I know that in this way we understand the stability rate of the system.

Comment: Then something is inconsistent in what you state. (your §4) cuz if speaking about avg / stdev the lower the ratio the higher stdev => the higher the dispersion. So contrarily with what stated in §4 the higher that ratio, the better. Please do ensure you definitely not mean stdev / avg.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the increase in deviation is negative, but it reduces the percentage after avg/stdev and shows the performance better.
I actually meant to express the following;
if the standard deviation is about 10 percent of the average value, then the system is optimal.